# Where was Sam Drake when Nathan was in Cartagena?

Tags: uncharted

In *Uncharted 3*, the flashback at the beginning shows Nathan meeting Sully while trying to steal Francis Drake's artifacts alone from a museum in Colombia. However, *Uncharted 4* establishes that this would have been after Nathan and Sam were on the run together, and they're still working as part of a team in *4*'s second flashback ~10 years later.

Does *Uncharted 4* or any information from Naughty Dog explain why Sam didn't come along to get the artifacts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** since Sam wasn't planned when they made *Uncharted 3*, it's technically a plot hole. However, the writers dropped enough indications here and there so that we can come up with an in-universe answer.

---

## Out-of-universe

Out of universe, Sam is a [retroactive continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity) (retcon), meaning that he is backstory material added after said backstory had been established.

In an interview given to VentureBeat, creator Neil Druckmann stated that Sam's character was really put into motion for *Uncharted 4*.

> **GamesBeat: Was Sam always part of this story? Was he conceived way back in the early days of the franchise?**
>
> **Druckmann:** No. There was a lot of discussion, around the time of Uncharted one, about who Nathan Drake is. Is Drake his real name? Where did he get the ring from? We would brainstorm ideas. A brother might come up in those brainstorms. Or his dad. His dad took different permutations. But that was never pinned down. Nothing like that was pinned down until Uncharted 4.
>
> <sub>[*The comprehensive interview with Uncharted 4 creators Neil Druckmann and Bruce Straley*, VentureBeat, May 27, 2016](https://venturebeat.com/2016/05/27/the-comprehensive-interview-with-uncharted-4-creators-neil-druckmann-and-bruce-straley/2/)</sub>

Given that "nothing was pinned down until *Uncharted 4*", Sam not being mentioned in *Uncharted 3*'s Cartagena flashback is simply due to Sam not being a thing yet.

It's not the only Sam-related plot hole; for instance, when Marlowe exposes Nathan's backstory in Yemen, she mentions the father who abandoned him, a suicidal mother, but no brother. Marlowe likes the mind tricks, had she known about a long-lost brother, she would definitely have mentioned him.

> Mother commits suicide... Father surrenders son to the state at the age of five... Entrusted to the St. Francis Boys Home... It's all so Dickensian.

This is not a case of "Nathan doesn't speak about Sam because he still grieves"; Marlowe has what seems to be [the whole Nathan Drake files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REHNX.png); including one from the orphanage, which would have mentioned Sam.

## In-universe

However, there's a line from *Uncharted 4*'s seventeenth chapter which might provide an in-universe answer about where Sam was during the Colombia events:

> You know, for a while it felt like... if we weren't taking turns going to jail... it was because we were in jail together.

It could have been, then, that Sam was somewhere in jail while Nathan was trying to steal the ring at the Cartagena exhibition. As to whether Nathan wasn't trying to break him out, either they used to wait for the sentence to end, or they were on a short schedule - notice that [the exhibition's sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KuIo.png) reads "Solamente esta semana" ("Only this week").

This is also kind of supported by the fact that Sam appears to know Sully in *Uncharted 4*. When Sam and Nathan meet up with Sully at Rossi Estate, Italy, the two act like they're familiar and haven't seen each other in a while.

> NATE: You remember my dead brother, right?
>
> SAM: Victor.
>
> SULLY: I'll be goddamned. Fifteen years...
>
> SAM: Yep.
>
> SULLY: Good to see you alive, Sam.

Since *Uncharted 4* begins in November 2015 (according to [the calendar in Nate's office](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdNd4.jpg)), the "fifteen years" mentioned by Sully would make their last meeting somewhere around 2000. The Cartagena flashback takes place "twenty years earlier" than *Uncharted 3*, and obviously *Uncharted 3* happens before *Uncharted 4*, so Sam and Sully had met before. Here, it's easier with a timeline:

[image: Timeline]

Point being, the in-universe "Sam was in jail, exited afterwards, and met Sully at some point" explanation holds up.